# auto save script for windows (Shift + Win + S) hotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, python, hotkeys

Windows has an inbuilt hotkey **(Win + Shift + S)** which executes snipping tool in rectangular strip mode, any screen captured will be copied to the clipboard as an image.

I am currently working on finding the most efficient way, in which we can pair the inbuilt shortcut key, with some script that automatically executes once a snip has been taken, and saves the snip automatically to a specific location.

I have already tried using **Keyboard**, **pyautogui** etc modules in **Python** for getting/creating keyboard events. The problem is that these modules are really slow and not consistent especially on slow hardware.

I am looking forward to a solution that makes use of windows inbuilt shortcut, and works over it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't want to install a new software/application

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @A__ Sadly No. But a good news is that now (on latest windows 10 build) once you take a screenshot via `Win` + `Shift` + `S`, you get a option of saving/customizing it as soon as it is taken. But that doesn't actually solve the problem in of ***Grabbing windows inbuilt shortcut and working over it***.  I achieved little success via using `autohotkey`, as it overrides the inbuilt shortcut but it also has its own share of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

As I understood the desired solution is expected as a -

> ..script that automatically executes once a snip has been taken, and saves the snip automatically to a specific location.

I will expand on "**Use Task Scheduler to run a Powershell batch script**" idea.
This idea is not new and I am surprised this is not answered yet in fullest. So here we go..

### Step 1: Task Scheduler

This will launch a Powershell script when User is logged in.

- Open Task Scheduler and hit "*Create Task...*"
- On the **General** Tab set the task to be `run whether the user is logged in or not` and `Do not store passwords` - these make Powershell script start in hiding

[image: general-tab]

- On the **Triggers** tab, create a Trigger to be `An log on` and select your User below

[image: triggers-tab]

- On the **Actions** tab, create an Action `Start a program` with `powershell` to be our program with following Argument -

```
-Command "Get-Content -Path 'D:\Apps\Windows Powershell Scripts\ScreenSnip Manager\Activate.ps1' -Raw | Invoke-Expression"
```

In short, the argument instructs the Powershell to load the lines of our script as one line and then execute it, thus going around the usual Windows restrictions regarding launching standalone scripts.

**Note:** The path to the script must be valid and must contain the file hereby named "Activate.ps1".

[image: add-action]

This concludes the Task. Close the Scheduler and let's move on.

### Step 2: Powershell script

Foreword: Windows does create 3 files after the Snip - Screenshot, its Thumbnail (always 364x180 on my FullHD setup) and a Json file. All files are dumped to the same system directory `ScreenClip`, which as of Win10 21H1 is located at `C:\Users\Your-username\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`. Our job in the loop is rather simple -

- monitor the folder for the new files appearing there
- then get the right picture
- rename/copy to desired userspace folder
- optionally clear out the `ScreenClip` folder

Next, **create a file** "Activate.ps1" *somewhere*. In my example, I have it stored at `D:\Apps\Windows Powershell Scripts\ScreenSnip Manager\Activate.ps1`

Content of the script

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher;

$watcher.Path = "$HOME\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip";

$watcher.Filter = "*.png";

$watcher.NotifyFilter = "FileName";

$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true;

$action = {

    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath;

    # Last chance for a file to unlock;
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100;
    
    try {

        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing;

        # Open image file;
        $png = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile((Get-Item $path));

        $dimensions = -join ($png.Width, " x ", $png.Height);

        # Skip automatic thumbnails which are always the same size;
        If ($dimensions -ne "364 x 180") {
             Copy-Item -Path $path -Destination "$HOME\Downloads\Screenshot-$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss.fff).png"; 
        }
        
    } catch {
        
        Write-Host "Problem acquiring image";

    } finally {
        
        $png.Dispose();
    }

}

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName "Created" -SourceIdentifier 'SnipGrab' -Action $action;

Remove-Item -Path (Join-Path $watcher.Path '\*') -Recurse;

while ($true){  Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier "SnipGrab";  };
```

As the code suggests, Snips are copied to the `Username\Downloads` folder and get renamed to something like `Screenshot-2021-05-17-213501.033.png`. Make sure to tweak the desired path and resulting file names.

There is really nothing complicated in the script from the first look, but it had bumps. Images must be handled cautiosly and resources released in code. A freshly created original snip is often not available at the same moment - its content is still being written to disk thus I added *100 ms* waiting time for the file write to complete. I am happy to finally compile the bits from here and there into the working variant. This is my literally second Powershell script and it took a night to read the docs and test things. Hope it helps)

Comment: Nice answer +1. I think the problem basically boiled down to discovering the location of the temporary saved image files, and then creating a watchdog on that location for new images.

Comment: Thanks for the script! It works fine, except that there are still two images created (a high-res one, and a smaller one, but the small one is not 364x180, the size varies). Any way to just save the native resolution image?

Comment: Nevermind, the small size is always the same, but it's `546 x 270` in my case, which is 1.5x larger. I assume this is because of the screen DPI/scaling factor which is for 150% on my 4k screen.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** It was later discovered (in Oct. 2020) from a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/aia21t/snip_sketch/elt5ajt/) that windows already temporarily saves a file of any screen snip captured in one of its *Windows ShellExperience Host* folders which introduced the idea of using a power shell script instead to accomplish the task of copying the temporarily created file and making it permanent by copying it to a designated location. This method was later provided (in May 2021) as an answer from Anton and is now the marked solution.

*The below, and original answer, has been slightly revised to improve its quality and is left for posterity as an alternative to using a PowerShell script (in case you do not have/or activated the use of PowerShell). However, it is not a complete automation of the entire process unless coupled with the use of AutoHotKey as later mentioned.*

---

I was considering working on such a script for quite some time as I found myself often using the Screen Snip tool numerous times and the hassle of *clicking and opening then hitting save and designating a name* became quite a nuisance AND time consuming.

Although I eventually gave in to using third party software (which was only maybe a 2MB install btw- [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/)). This is what I had come up with at the time:

## Overview

The general idea is to help expedite the process of saving the snip once a snip has been taken, whereas paint opens automatically and the user will need to manually hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to quickly paste and save. It includes:

- Use **Event Viewer** to track whenever *Screen Snip* is used and act as the trigger
- Use Task Scheduler to <strike>commit the action of saving</strike> expedite the action of saving by immediately opening paint to output the saved snip from clipboard

~**OR**~

- Use Task Scheduler to run a Powershell batch script (as explained by Anton's answer)
- Use Task Scheduler to run **AutoHotKey** script to automatically open paint, paste, and save the file for you *(but involves third party software contrary to the OP's original request)*

### Step 1: Enable the trigger used by Event Viewer

- Run *secpol.msc* (AKA **Local Security Policy**)
- On the left go to *Local Policies* then *Audit Policy*
- Then Double Click "*Audit process tracking*" and mark the checkbox for "*Success*"

### Step 2: Create scheduled task based on that trigger

This will automatically open paint whenever the Screen Snip tool is used

- Open Task Scheduler and hit "*Create Task...*" *(Making sure NOT to use *Create basic task*)
- On the **General** Tab, name the task whatever you'd like
- On the **Triggers** tab, click "New", and for the drop down menu selection "*Begin the task:*" select "*On an event*"
- Select "Custom" then click "New Event Filter..."
- At the top, select the "XML" tab and hit the checkbox for "Edit Query Manually" and enter one of the following:

  - **Option 1:**
    if you want Paint to open immediately after you make your selection so that it can be pasted and saved:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]] 
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\backgroundTaskHost.exe')]] 
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='ProcessId'] and (Data='0x54c')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

As a forewarning, he above option attempts to limit the process from being trigger by other applications using `BackgroundTaskHost` by specifying the Process ID (which you can obtain from Event Viewer) However, it is possible the Process ID *can* change and *why this complicates matters when trying to use Screen Snip from Snip & Sketch while having some form of "automatic" save*

- **Option 2**:
  Is mildly less automatic and requires you click the notification that pops up after you make a Screen Snip in order to trigger it running:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13312 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4688)]] 
   and 
     *[EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_10.1907.2471.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ScreenSketch.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

This is because Screen Snip is constantly running in the background and when you create the screen snip, the process used is `BackgroundTaskHost` as a subprocess of `RuntimeBroker` and `svchost`. Thus, in order to make the event trigger particular to screen snip (Snip & Sketch), you would need to click on the preview image notification that pops up in order to bring Snip & Sketch from a *background process* to **Active Task*

- Click `OK` and `OK` to return to the Task creation window.

### Step 3 - Designating the Task To be Accomplish

- Now go to the *Actions* tab
- Select "New..."
- The default "Action:" should be "Start a program" if not select it
- Then browse to mspaint.exe (usually `%windir%\system32\mspaint.exe`)
- hit `OK` and `OK` and you're set

Now paint will automatically open after a snip is made allowing you to immediately paste and save the file.

*[Edit note: At the time, there was no solution provided and the above answer was a contribution provided in the hopes of providing some sort of answer. In hindsight, it seems rudimentary but perhaps it will be found useful to a small subset of individuals]*

## Alternative Actions for Task Scheduler

Below are some alternative actions I explored in attempting to accomplish this during the time of writing of this answer:

- Use a [Powershell batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/1049363/windows-utility-tool-command-line-to-move-clipboard-to-file) *For your benefit, this method doesn't require third party program and is fortunately covered by Anton's later provided answer*
- Using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/99650-screen-grab-and-paste-in-paint/) to actually make the entire process automatic, no longer requiring user input.

Personally, before figuring all of this out, I had already given up and downloaded, installed, and utilized Greenshot yet my insatiable desire to provide an answer had left me publishing this 6 hours later.

Comment: Apparently the screenshots also get dumped to a certain location in %APPDATA%, so perhaps it might be more productive to simply monitor that folder? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/snipping-tool-win-shift-s-screenshot-save-location/1ad3bb2a-9a0d-449a-a52a-7076f1508acf

Comment: Wow, great find, thank you @ChristianMann!! This simplify things by A LOT. Apparently it's one or two possible directories but in my case, I found it to be "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip" 

So now, all you have to do is to have a script duplicate the file every time a new file is generated in the folder, and have it pasted to whatever folder is most convenient. By now, I've gotten used to my third party software but learning new ways to attack an old problem is definitely insightful, sincere thanks!

Comment: @Doedigo +1 Sorry for late reply. The answer is a good alternative to the accepted solution. Also could you guide me, to where I can find information/guide regarding *Event Viewer*, as I am not much literate in using it.

Comment: @VasuDeo.S Thank you. To clarify, Event Viewer is the title of the program used to view entries in the Windows Event Log, more information can be found at  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/using-windows-event-log whereas windows 10 introduced TraceLogging and would be the equivalent I believe, of the event log and event viewer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tracelogging/trace-logging-portal